# API V1 RESTful. I got "Unknown error" when added line break to JSON. Is it OK?

Tags: rest, api, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

I'm testing API queries and sending POST with such body:

```
{
"books": "12",
"available": "true",
"id": "qwe2323-2342rfws-23r2rfew"
}
```

I got 200 response - OK.

But when I add line break to one of the string data, e.g.:

```
{
"books": "12",
"available": "true",
"id": "qwe2323-2342rfws-23r
2rfew"
}
```

I got 500 "Unknown error".

**My question:** Can the server recognize this error and return a response, for example, *WRONG_ID*? In fact, I just added a line break character to the identifier string. In theory, the script should see the forbidden symbol without problems and return the corresponding error. Can I give such a recommendation to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The *payload* is **INVALID** which generates an exception at the server and responded with 500 as it cannot understand the data payload.

To check the payload and show a **INVALID JSON DATA** or through any custom message, you can check the payload on every POST request at the server side, as in below example for PHP programming language:

```
private function handleRequest(Request $request, Programmer $programmer)
{
    // ...

    if ($data === null) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Invalid JSON: '.$request->getContent());
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Reference:**
https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/rest/error-invalid-json#handling-invalid-json

Comment: I mean line break as a typo in the request body, but not \r\n combination. I can't (and no need) decode/encode strings. I only testing the app. I understood that 500 code is not proper in this case. But what ideally should response the server when it get JSON with broken line (as in example)? Can it return e.g. 422 with message ("WROND ID" or "FORBIDDEN SYMBOLS IN ID" or "ID NOT FOUND")? Thanks.

Comment: @Jurchello What programming language you are for the REST API ?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know.

Comment: @Jurchello You can check the payload at the server side, as in below example for PHP https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/rest/error-invalid-json#handling-invalid-json